# Play + ReactiveMongo: capped collection and tailable cursor

Tags: mongodb, scala, playframework, reactivemongo, capped-collections

I'm using Play Framework with Scala, Akka and ReactiveMongo. I want to use a collection in MongoDB as a circular queue. Several actors can insert documents into it; one actor retrieves these documents as soon as they're available (a sort of publish-subscribe system). 
I'm using capped collections and tailable cursor. Everytime I retrieve some documents I have to run the command EmptyCapped to flush the capped collection (it's not possible to REMOVE elements from it) otherwise I retrieve always the same document. is there an alternative solution? for example is there a way to slide a cursor without removing elements? or it's better not to use capped collection in my case?

```
object MexDB {

def db: reactivemongo.api.DB = ReactiveMongoPlugin.db
val size: Int = 10000

// creating capped collection
val collection: JSONCollection = {

    val c = db.collection[JSONCollection]("messages")

    val isCapped = coll.convertToCapped(size, None)

    Await.ready(isCapped, Duration.Inf)

    c
}

def insert(mex: Mex) = {

    val inserted = collection.insert(mex)

    inserted onComplete {
      case Failure(e) =>
        Logger.info("Error while inserting task: " + e.getMessage())
        throw e

      case Success(i) =>
        Logger.info("Successfully inserted task")
    }

}


def find(): Enumerator[Mex] = {

  val cursor: Cursor[Mex] = collection
    .find(Json.obj())
    .options(QueryOpts().tailable.awaitData)
    .cursor[Mex]

    // meaning of maxDocs ???
    val maxDocs = 1
    cursor.enumerate(maxDocs)
}


def removeAll() = {
    db.command(new EmptyCapped("messages"))
}
```

}

```
/*** part of receiver actor code ***/

// inside preStart
val it = Iteratee.fold[Mex, List[Mex]](Nil) {
    (partialList, mex) => partialList ::: List(mex)
}

// Inside "receive" method
case Data =>

  val e: Enumerator[Mex] = MexDB.find()

  val future = e.run(it)

  future onComplete {
    case Success(list) =>
      list foreach { mex =>
        Logger.info("Mex: " + mex.id)
      }
      MexDB.removeAll()
      self ! Data

    case Failure(e) => Logger.info("Error:  "+ e.getMessage())
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your tailable cursor is closed after each found doc as the `maxDocs = 1`. To keep it open indefinitely you should omit this limit.

With `awaitData`, `.onComplete` will only be called if you explicitly shutdown RM.

You need to use some streaming function from the cursor, such as `.enumerate` and process each new step/result. See https://github.com/sgodbillon/reactivemongo-tailablecursor-demo/

Comment: Thanks. So if I omit that limit I can create the enumerator just once and re-use it right?  Is there an alternative way to retrieve documents from capped collection like a circular queue without running EmptyCapped every time?

Comment: Max 1 only read one doc. Remove the limit and the cursor is kept open at its current 'position', not back to the first doc.

Comment: I removed the limit, I created just once the cursor and the enumerator. I periodically execute:

val future = enum.run(it)
future onComplete { *** }

I'm inserting periodically mex in the collection but enum never retrieves some mex... what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do i need to inject Input.Done into my enumerator?

Comment: With `awaitData`, `onComplete` will only be called if you explicitly shutdown RM. You need to use some streaming function from the cursor, such as `enumerate` and process each new step/result. See https://github.com/sgodbillon/reactivemongo-tailablecursor-demo/blob/master/app/controllers/Application.scala

Comment: Nope. Approach waiting for completion won't work as the cursor is not supposed to end, but to return results in a streaming way.